# Store files with carrierwave to remote server (may be via ssh/scp)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Im setting up production environment where all static content are separated from web application server. I need to store all carrierwave powered content to another server, but by default carrierwave include only :file (for local files) and :fog (for cloud CDN) store support. How I can do that?

SOLUTION:
Seems like I found solution: [carrierwave-ftp gem](https://github.com/luan/carrierwave-ftp). I'll test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: [carrierwave-ftp](https://github.com/luan/carrierwave-ftp) gem supports ftp/sftp uploading.